# "edited" key always return false. even though it shows edited on site

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, comments

CommentID: `1193255` On site `Meta Stack Exchange`

The Api returns `edited` as `false`

[image]

However if you see the comment itself, you can see it has been edited.

Is there something that I am missing here?

[image]